# Dynamic API Calls in React Native Application

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The main issue I'm having is getting the value from a stored key from localstorate and making sure I can use it in a dynamic API url in order to retrieve data from an API call.

The app concept is a Bible Study Application. The First Code File represents the the collection of verses the user sees on a page, and the Second Code File acts as a view for the verse selected by the user with the Verse's contents/details.

The issue I'm having is scope on the screen's loading. Essentially, I'm trying to retrieve a value from AsyncStorage and use it to construct a dynamic API URL for fetching data. I initially wanted to achieve this utilizing states/route.params but I keep getting an error that the route.params are undefined (don't exist).

When I navigate from the page and click on another verse to display on the page, the page isn't reloading the next text, it seems like the API is only calling once for render, and it won't render the new verse selected unless I completely reload the app. How can I or what can I do to once I select a new verse, the API recalls a new display on data on the page.

What am I doing wrong in this regard?

Screen 1 (Card.js)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Block, Text, theme } from 'galio-framework';
import { argonTheme } from '../constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Card = ({ item, horizontal, full, style, ctaColor, imageStyle }) => {
  
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [selectedVerseReference, setSelectedVerseReference] = useState('');

  this.state = {
    verseReference: "Test",
  };
  
  const viewVerse = (verseReference) => {
    
    setSelectedVerseReference(verseReference);
    console.log("State Set: " + selectedVerseReference);  

    // Clear and Reset Verse KeyStorage
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    AsyncStorage.setItem('verse-key', verseReference);

    // Console Log for Testing ...
    // console.log("Reference KEY from press: " + verseReference);

    // After Setting up the storage... 
    // Navigate to Next Page...
    navigation.navigate(item.link, { verseReference: verseReference }); 


  }

  const imageStyles = [
    full ? styles.fullImage : styles.horizontalImage,
    imageStyle
  ];

  const cardContainer = [styles.card, styles.shadow, style];
  const imgContainer = [
    styles.imageContainer,
    horizontal ? styles.horizontalStyles : styles.verticalStyles,
    styles.shadow
  ];

  return (
    <Block row={horizontal} card flex style={cardContainer}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => console.log('OK Pressed')}>
        <Block flex style={imgContainer}></Block>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => viewVerse(item.kjv_verse_keyphrase)}>
        <Block flex space="between" style={styles.cardDescription}>
          <Text size={16} style={styles.cardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text size={12} muted={!ctaColor} color={ctaColor || argonTheme.COLORS.ACTIVE} bold>{item.link}</Text>
          <Text size={12} muted={!ctaColor} color={ctaColor || argonTheme.COLORS.ACTIVE} bold>{item.kjv_verse_keyphrase}</Text>
        </Block>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Block>
  );
}

Card.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object,
  navigation:  PropTypes.object,
  horizontal: PropTypes.bool,
  full: PropTypes.bool,
  ctaColor: PropTypes.string,
  imageStyle: PropTypes.any,
}

// Styles for the page

export default Card;
```

Screen 2 (Verse.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, ScrollView, Image, ImageBackground, Platform, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { Block, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";
import { Button } from "../components";
import { Images, argonTheme } from "../constants";
import { HeaderHeight } from "../constants/utils";
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Environment & Screen
import {REACT_APP_ESV_API_KEY, REACT_APP_KJV_API_KEY} from '@env';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

// Just to measure the width and dimension of the page so elements can fit properly.
const thumbMeasure = (width - 48 - 32) / 3;

// I will probably need to do a verse state data here, in order to catch the specific ID this is coming from (and don't forget switches between ESV and KJV)

const Verse = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();  

  // Load State and Core Variables
  const [getValue, setGetValue] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [verseContent, setVerseContent] = useState([]);  
  const [selectedVerseReference, setSelectedVerseReference] = useState(''); // Added state

  // const { verseReference } = route.params;  

  if (selectedVerseReference) { console.log("Keyphrase " +  selectedVerseReference);  } else { console.log("No state set for Keyphrase");  }


  // Retrieve Variable from LocalStorage 
  useEffect(() => {
    // ==== [ getValueFromStorage ] ========
    const getValueFromStorage = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('verse-key'); 
        
      if (value) {
        setGetValue(value); 
      }
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching value from AsyncStorage:', error);
      }
    };

    getValueFromStorage(); 

  }, []);

// ==========================================================
  // Fetch Verse Data (1st Render)
 // ==========================================================
  useEffect(() => {
    
    // ==== [ getValue ] ========
    if (getValue) {
      const fetchVerseData = async () => {
        try {
          const fullURLstructure = constructApiUrl(getValue);  
          console.log("Full URL Structure #1: " + fullURLstructure);
          const response = await fetch(fullURLstructure, {
            // method: 'POST', 
            headers:{
              'api-key': REACT_APP_KJV_API_KEY,
          },
          body: data,
          });
          const data = await response.json();
          setVerseContent(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching verse data:', error);
        }
      };

      fetchVerseData();
        
    }

    
  }, [getValue]);
// ==========================================================
// Fetch Verse Data (2nd Render)
// ==========================================================
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data based on the new verse reference
    const fetchVerseData = async () => {
      try {
        const fullURLstructure = constructApiUrl(verseReference); 
        console.log("Full URL Structure #2: " + fullURLstructure); 
        const response = await fetch(fullURLstructure, {
            // method: 'POST', 
            headers:{
              'api-key': REACT_APP_KJV_API_KEY,
          },
          body: data,
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setVerseContent(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching verse data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchVerseData();
  }, [selectedVerseReference]);   // [TODO:] Trigger the effect whenever verseReference changes )?)   

  // Need to retrieve data incoming from the previous page, in a variable to construct the API query.
  const constructApiUrl = (verseValue) => {
    const baseBibleURL = 'https://api.bibliosexample.com/v3/xljsnfuoalkls/passages/';  
    return `${baseBibleURL}${verseValue}`;
  };
   
  // On Application Loading ...
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  // On Application No Data Found ...
  if (!verseContent) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Verse data not found.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  // Structure needed for specific parsing of the HTML Format for text coming to the page. for Render HTML
  const source = {
    html: verseContent.data.content
  };

  return (


  <Block flex style={styles.profile}>
      <Block flex>

        <ImageBackground source={Images.ProfileBackground} style={styles.profileContainer} imageStyle={styles.profileBackground}>

            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{ width, marginTop: '10%' }} >


              <Block flex style={styles.profileCard}>
    
                <Block flex>
                  <Block middle style={styles.nameInfo}>

                    <Text bold size={28} color="#32325D">{ verseReference }</Text>
                    <Text size={16} color="#32325D" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>{verseContent.data.reference}</Text>

                  </Block>

                  {/* Divider */}
                  <Block middle style={{ marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 16 }}><Block style={styles.divider} /></Block>
                  
                  <Block middle>
                  
                  <RenderHtml contentWidth={width} source={source}/>
                    <Button color="transparent" textStyle={{color: "#233DD2",fontWeight: "500",fontSize: 16}}>
                      Read Full Verse
                    </Button>

                    <Block style={styles.info}>

                    </Block>
                </Block>

                  
                  <Block style={{ paddingBottom: -HeaderHeight * 2 }}></Block>


                  {/* ================================ */}
                </Block>
              </Block>
            </ScrollView>
          </ImageBackground>
        </Block>

      </Block>

  );
};

// Styles for the page

export default Verse;
```

Comment: Provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: This is a bit of a wild guess, but what you describe about the rerenders is most likely because you need to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/ instead of `useEffect`. With `react-navigation`, it actually keeps screens the user has previously seen in memory and pulls them back out again when they navigate back without rendering. It does this in order to be able to meet performance criteria users expect with native apps. With `useFocusEffect` it will run when you are thinking it does.

Comment: In addition to this, you were right the first time with using params for this and not storage, which is overly-global state to solve this. But let's take one thing at a time and try `useFocusEffect` first, which either way is still part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you @adsy, I reworked the code and now I'm getting the Fetch to repopulate dynamically using useFocusEffect vs useEffect. Now I have to figure out the memory issue, With replacing useEffect, there's now a continuous loop that I have to put a stoppage on, but I'm very happy to get a bit further, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: No worries! Typically that's because the deps of the effect are changing on every render, or that the effect contents themselves actually mutates the deps. Make sure every dep is memoized. Though I can't actually see this issue in the code you posted thus far because the only dep there is `getValue` and that's directly from `useState` which means its referentially stable across renders anyway. Hmmm.

Comment: Again, I can't thank you enough @adsy for the point in the right direction,